# Kubernetes CronJob Not exited

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-cronjob

I am running a cronjob in kubernetes. Cronjob started and but not exited. Status of pod is always in **RUNNING**.
Below is logs

```
kubectl get pods
cronjob-1623253800-xnwwx   1/1     Running            0          13h
```

When i describe the **JOB** below are noticed

```
kubectl describe job cronjob-1623300120

Name:           cronjob-1623300120
Namespace:      cronjob
Selector:      xxxxx 
Labels:         xxxxx
Annotations:    <none>
Controlled By:  CronJob/cronjob
Parallelism:    1
Completions:    1
Start Time:     Thu, 9 Jun 2021 10:12:03 +0530
Pods Statuses:  1 Running / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=cronjob
           controller-xxxx
           job-name=cronjob-1623300120
  Containers:
   plannercronjob:
    Image:      xxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Mounts:                             <none>
  Volumes:                              <none>
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age    From            Message
  ----    ------            ----   ----            -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  13h  job-controller  Created pod: cronjob-1623300120
```

I Noticed that Pods Statuses:  1 Running / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed. This means that the when code return zero , then job Succeeded/Failed. Is that correct ?.

When i enter into the pod using execute command

```
kubectl exec --stdin --tty cronjob-1623253800-xnwwx -n cronjob -- /bin/bash

root@cronjob-1623253800-xnwwx:/# ps ax| grep python
    1 ?        Ssl    0:01 python -m sfit.src.app
   18 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep python
```

I found that python process is still running. Is this a code issue deadlock or something else.

```
pod describe
Name:         cronjob-1623302220-xnwwx
Namespace:    default
Priority:     0
Node:         aks-agentpool-xxxxvmss000000/10.240.0.4
Start Time:   Thu, 9 Jun 2021 10:47:02 +0530
Labels:       app=cronjob
              controller-uid=xxxxxx
              job-name=cronjob-1623302220
Annotations:  <none>
Status:       Running
IP:           10.244.1.30
IPs:
  IP:           10.244.1.30
Controlled By:  Job/cronjob-1623302220
Containers:
  plannercronjob:
    Container ID:   docker://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    Image: xxxxxxxxxxx
    Image ID:       docker-xxxx
    Port:           <none>
    Host Port:      <none>
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 9 Jun 2021 10:47:06 +0530
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-97xzv (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True 
  Ready             True 
  ContainersReady   True 
  PodScheduled      True 
Volumes:
  default-token-97xzv:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-97xzv
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From                                        Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----                                        -------
  Normal  Scheduled  13h   default-scheduler                           Successfully assigned cronjob/cronjob-1623302220-xnwwx to aks-agentpool-xxx-vmss000000
  Normal  Pulling    13h   kubelet, aks-agentpool-xxx-vmss000000  Pulling image "xxxx.azurecr.io/xxx:1.1.1"
  Normal  Pulled     13h   kubelet, aks-agentpool-xxx-vmss000000  Successfully pulled image "xxx.azurecr.io/xx:1.1.1"
  Normal  Created    13h   kubelet, aks-agentpool-xxx-vmss000000  Created container cronjob
  Normal  Started    13h   kubelet, aks-agentpool-xxx-vmss000000  Started container cronjob
```

@KrishnaChaurasia  . I run the docker image in my system. There is some error in  my  python code. But it is exit with error.  But in the kubernetes it is not exited and not stop

```
docker run xxxxx/cronjob:1    
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azure/core/pipeline/transport/_requests_basic.py", line 261, in send
        raise error
    azure.core.exceptions.ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f113f6480a0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

> echo $?
> 1

Comment: yes, most likely issue with the code.. could you also add the output of `kubectl logs <pod-name>`? that will clarify further what is currently running in the pod.

Comment: I put some print in code. But these are not printed. Just showing a blank  log while issuing kubectl logs  -f <podname>

Comment: what if you describe the pod as well? currently, the output that you have added has `kubectl describe job`. could you look for the output of pod as well to see if there is more info..

Comment: pod describe added in post. not seen unusually

Comment: most likely the actual code is the problem but can't really say what's going wrong without seeing the python code or any logs.. as a workaround, you could try to create a docker container using the image (`docker run`) and use `docker logs` to see if the issue replicates outside of k8s.

Comment: thank you @KrishnaChaurasia so much

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia . i run the  docker and there is some error in python code but code exit and shows the error. But in the kubernetes pod is not showing any error. i update the details in question

Comment: try to use a new image name every time you create a new build; many a times, I have observed that the updated scripts are not used by the pods if we use the same image name due to k8s caching issues.

Comment: i am always using same image name.but i delete the current job and creating new if there is any image change occurs. is that the issue?

Comment: as mentioned, I have seen caching issues where using the same tag after updating the scripts doesn't update the image in the cluster so it could be that the cronjob is using the same scripts.. you can verify the same by exec'ing in to jobs' pod and `cat` the file provide it has `bash` and `cat` installed. deleting the cron job will not help with the image caching issue if it is there.

Comment: Thanks @KrishnaChaurasia . i will recreating image every time.. One more doubt . When i create new image , what happend to old image. that still present or deleted ?

Comment: I am not sure, docker has some built-in garbage collector to delete unused images and there are tools to create image deletion strategies but I don't know much about it. found some doc at [kubelet-garbage-collection](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/kubelet-garbage-collection/)

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia, Could you post your solution as an answer?

Comment: hi @MikołajGłodziak, I think that OP has not acknowledged what the actual problem was and whether any of my comments have solved the issue so I'll leave them as comments for now.

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia . Acutal issue is in the code . i run the docker image in  my local PC. In my local pc same way the docker is not exited. Then i tried to enter into the kubernetes pod and check any python code is running or not. (kubectl exec -it cronjob-1623253800-xnwwx  -- ./../bin/bash)
using ps ax| grep python command

Comment: there is python file running and that stuck due to some reason. so that pod is showing in running state

Answer (score 0):

If you are seeing your pod is always running and never completed, try to add staratingDeadlineSeconds.

https://medium.com/@hengfeng/what-does-kubernetes-cronjobs-startingdeadlineseconds-exactly-mean-cc2117f9795f